# OneDrive for business Oauth2 with REST

Tags: onedrive

I have portal.office.com account and want to access OneDrive for business at tenant-my.sharepoint.com by means of my REST application.
I have registered my application in Azure Active Directory and starting Oauth2 authentication like this:

https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id='+ App.Key + '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8889/';

On this phase I have got AuthCode from azure and next phase is obtaining session tokens.

As next step in authentication I'm doing POST request to https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token
with params:
'client_id=' + App.Key
+ 'client_secret=' + App.Secret
+ 'code=' + AuthCode
+ 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:8889/'
+ 'grant_type=authorization_code'
+ 'resource='+URLEncode('syncovery1');

Unfortunately I'm getting error in response:
{"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS50001: The application named syncovery1 was not found in the tenant named konnov.onmicrosoft.com. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 1af2ced2-b2bb-4568-8a87-bd2d1186cf9a\r\nCorrelation ID: 15dcda2c-0599-4279-8744-27c61e6912a9\r\nTimestamp: 2015-10-06 07:46:03Z","error_codes":[50001],"timestamp":"2015-10-06 07:46:03Z","trace_id":"1af2ced2-b2bb-4568-8a87-bd2d1186cf9a","correlation_id":"15dcda2c-0599-4279-8744-27c61e6912a9"}'

Please suggest the ways to a possible solution. In my portal.office.com account I can not find any place where third party application might be associated with the account. Can you guess the meaning of the 'resource' param in the last request?
What services or licences in portal.office.com should be active to allow authentication? Maybe I just don't have OneDriveForBusiness subscription activated?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Resource in the request means the resource which you want to access in the particular tenant. And so the Resource should be the **App Id** which you have registered in azure ad **("not App name")**. If 'syncovery1' is the name of the application then it returns error. And one more point to add, do not encode the resource as the endpoint may not recognize it. And

For example, if you want to get all the resource endpoint of office365 then the resource would be - _https://api.office.com/discovery/.

Similarly, if the App id of my app is _https://mydrive.sharepoint.com/ registered with app name as "mydrivesync", then the resource should be _https://mydrive.sharepoint.com/.

Follow this [official documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm) for complete details.